# "Cannot resolve keyword 'user' into field. Choices are: id, project_, user_"

Tags: django, manytomanyfield

py like the following

```
class User_(models.Model):
user_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
user_password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
user_admin = models.BooleanField(False)

class Project_(models.Model):
project_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
users = models.ManyToManyField(User_)
project_path = models.FilePathField()
```

and now I tried to use the many_to_many field users in the following

```
    usr = User_.objects.get(user_name= userName) #it retrieves the correct object
    newProject = Project_(project_name=projectName)
    newProject.save()
    newProject.users.add(usr) #here is the error 
    newProject.save()
```

The error raised is:
"Cannot resolve keyword 'user' into field. Choices are: id, project_, user_"

I could not fix that error, Any help?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you copied the error message correctly? It seems to reference a keyword 'user' which doesn't exist on the line you indicated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your table names... remove the trailing underscores and it'll work fine.

Django creates an intermediary table for m2m fields called something like `APP_MODEL1_MODEL2`, and due to your underscores, there will be a double underscore in there which is confusing the ORM.